# Email going to spam while using SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, sendmail, amazon-ses

I am using SES to send mails to users. It works fine if I send the email with From address of Gmail but for the same mail, if I change to my company id it goes to spam.

I checked the domain MX and TXT settings and they look fine.

Any idea on what could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an SPF record?

Answer (score 3):

Like some of the previous posters have said, the first thing I would check is if there is an SPF record setup for the domain that you are sending from, which is causing the problem.  If not, you might want to try sending a message from your mail server to check-auth@verifier.port25.com.  You receive a report back with a ton of information, and it should show you if there is a glaring problem that you're not aware of which is causing spam filters to think your messages are spam.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two links:

DKIM:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-dkim.html

SPF:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-spf.html

You should enable both of these to allow email spam filters to be more lenient with emails sent from your SES registered addresses. It's a pain to set up, but a necessary pain unfortunately.

Here's an amusing technical read on the topic: http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/